# Install NIX packages offline

Tags: curl, nix

I sit behind a very restrictive proxy with limited access to some internet resources.  For instance, anything on the GNU Mirror http://ftpmirror.gnu.org is blocked.

I have just moved from HOMEBREW to NIX, with HOMEBREW I could save the tarballs under ~/.cache/Homebrew and `brew` command can detect them as "Already Downloaded" and can continue installation from there.

Does NIX provide anything similar?  Or any other solution to go around the error "error: unable to download ‘http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/diffutils/diffutils-3.6.tar.xz’: HTTP error 403 (curl error: No error)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIX offers a command line tool to do that, `nix-store --add /path/to/file`, which adds the file preceeded with the hash in its name to the store.

To prepopulate nix store with all the cached files from homebrew, one could do

```
nix-store --add ~/.cache/Homebrew/*
```

A more detailed blog post is available at http://lethalman.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/nix-pill-18-nix-store-paths.html